# How would you explain this graph illustration of Simpson's paradox?

Tags: probability, statistics, paradoxes

I need your help for understanding WHAT in the graph you find in the following link proves Simpson's Paradox. For those who don't know about Simpson's paradox, it is the inversion of the inequalities written in the link. I know for sure that the fact that those two quadrilaterals are symmetrical with respect to the bisector isn't the reason for SP, but what then?
Thank you in advance. 
http://dropseaofulaula.blogspot.it/2012/12/dimostrazioni-senza-parole-il-paradosso.html

Comment: I don't really understand the graph. For me, the best explanation of Simpson's paradox is done through causality, as for example in chapter 6 of Pearl's "Causality" book.

Answer (score 2):

Alice and Bob work at the same job for two years. The job consists of a sequence of projects, on which they can succeed or fail. In the first year Alice succeeds on $a_2$ projects and fails on $a_1$, while Bob succeeds on $A_2$ and fails on $A_1$. In the second year Alice succeeds on $b_2$ and fails on $b_1$, while Bob succeeds on $B_2$ and fails on $B_1$. Since

$$\frac{a_2}{a_1}<\frac{A_2}{A_1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{b_2}{b_1}<\frac{B_2}{B_1}\;,$$

Bob has a better ratio of successes to failures than Alice in each of the two years. But

$$\frac{a_2+b_2}{a_1+b_1}>\frac{A_2+B_2}{A_1+B_1}\;,$$

so overall Alice has a better ratio of successes to failures.

You can convert it this into a statement about probabilities of success, but even if you don’t, it’s Simpson’s paradox, and the graph shows very clearly how it can arise.

Comment: Simpson's paradox is clear. I am afraid I am not smart enough to understand why the graph is a proof to it. Would you be so kind to explain?

Comment: @Viviana: It’s not a proof: it’s an illustration of how Simpson’s paradox can arise — an illustration of an example of Simpson’s paradox in a way that makes it a little clearer how such a reversal can arise. I was simply explaining the connection between the graph and Simpson’s paradox, since that seemed to me the only thing that might not be apparent just from the image and the inequalities under it.